# R - Putting Google Places API data into a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, google-places-api

I've managed to extract all restaurants in my local area using Google Places API, i am struggling now however to get these into a dataframe (my ultimate aim being to then export this to excel).

I have the following code:

```
myPlaces <- google_places(location = myLocation, 
        place_type = "restaurant",
                        radius = 500,
                        key = key)

nextPlaces <- google_places(location = myLocation,
                            radius = 500,
                place_type = "restaurant",
                            page_token = myPlaces$next_page_token, 
                            key = key)

nextPlaces2 <- google_places(location = myLocation,
                            radius = 500,
                place_type = "restaurant",
                            page_token = nextPlaces$next_page_token, 
                            key = key)
```

This is getting me the data i want but when i try and create a data frame with it i fail with:

```
> df1 <- select(myPlaces, name, business_status, rating, types, price_level, geometry.location.lat, geometry.location.lng)
```

getting the error message "Error: `select()` doesn't handle lists."

I'm fairly new to R and its taken me many hours to this point, i feel like i'm close to my end goal but stumped by this. Ever so grateful for any help.

Thanks,

Comment: I have not worked with this package, before. But it seems that `google_places()` returns a list. If this list is just a list of vectors of equal length, you can transform it to a data.frame by writing: `df1 = as.data.frame(myPlaces)`. But it might have a more complex structure and you might need to check the documentation on what exactly is stored under what name in this list.

Comment: Would you mind to post `str(myPlaces)` and `head(myPlaces)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
myPlaces<- myPlaces$results

nextPlaces<- nextPlaces$results

nextPlaces2<- nextPlaces2$results
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add a quick explanation of how your code addresses the question asked.